# Замена значения массива

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, методы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать замену числовых значений в массиве не затрагивая строковые значения на javascript?
Пробовал регуляркой с replace не получается.
Заранее спасибо!

```
с этого массива значения 
["160.0", "438.0", "200.0.0", "-80.0", "80.0", "180.0"]

подставить в этот
["M", "260.0", "438.0", "l", "167.0.0", "-80.0", "80.0", "H", "180.0", "Z"]
```

Comment: Если всегда такая же последовательность, то проще функцию написать где сделать прямое сопоставление и не париться

Comment: А что на что должно меняться?

Comment: Массивы могут быть разные с разными буквами, буквы это кординаты, менятся должны только числа, к примеру с первого массива значения 160.0 должно подставится во второй массив по индексу 1, тоесть 160.0 на 260.0

Comment: давайте так...напишите пару примеров --- выходные данные...а то вопрос слишком не понятный...вангованием не занимаемся ) что откуда и как береться..объясняйте...важно чтобы любой мог понять закономерность, тогда вам помогут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если менять попросту по очереди будет как-то так :

```js
const dontTouch = ['M', 'L', 'l', 'H', 'h', 'V', 'C', 'c', 'S', 'Q', 'q', 'T', 'A', 'Z', 'z'],
  arrNumbers = ["160.0", "438.0", "200.0.0", "-80.0", "80.0", "180.0"],
  arr = ["M", "260.0", "438.0", "l", "167.0.0", "-80.0", "80.0", "H", "180.0", "Z"],
  replace = (a, r) => a.map(e => {
    if (~dontTouch.indexOf(e)) return e

    const v = r[0]
    r.shift()
    return v
  })


console.log(replace(arr, arrNumbers))
```

ПС: Должно быть так ?

Comment: Практически почти что да, только старое значения у которого по две плавающии точки, копируется в новый массив. на выходи получается вот так:
```
["M", "160.0", "438.0", "l", "167.0.0", "200.0.0", "-80.0", "H", "80.0", "Z"]
```

Comment: @Alex.M в моем ответе на виходе получаеться именно то что вы и написали... уточните плиз)

Comment: на выходе должно получится такой масив: `["M", "160.0", "438.0", "l", "200.0.0", "-80.0", "H", "80.0", "Z"]`. без дублирования старого значения, **"167.0.0"**.

Comment: вот только "200.0.0" ето кагбе не число в общем то, но понятно, какие еще значения щитаем числом ? просто если там есть цифри ?

Comment: Все кроме кроме букв, вот какие могут быть буквы в массиве: `
M, L, l, H, h, V, C, c, S, Q, q, T, A, Z, z
`
остальное это все значение, они могут быть как с двумя плавующими точками так и с тремя.

Comment: тоесть у вас есть конечний набор значений, которие НЕ нужно менять, верно ? если так то решение простое, смотрите

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно оставить неизменными элементы, в которых используются буквы. Также порядок элементов не должен измениться. Вот вариант фукнции, модифицирующей второй переданный массив:

```
function replaceCoords(sourceArray, targetArray) {
  const digitsRegExp = /[\d-]/;
  let j = 0;
  targetArray.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (digitsRegExp.test(item[0])) {
      targetArray[i] = sourceArray[j];
      j++;
    }
  });
}
```